# Avoid try catch when accesing to an non-existing object property

Tags: php, object, properties, try-catch

I have an object, and I print the value of a property:

```
echo $myObject->field_seo_multidomain->$lang_arr[$language]->$domains_arr[$domain]->field_seo->field_meta_description->value;
```

What have I to do to avoid an error when the property does not exist? For example, **$lang_arr[$language]** above (second level property) does not exist. I have used try-catch, and works well, but I am afraid that that could be time consuming or accumulate errors in some logging textfile or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a magic getter function and check the existence of the property like

```
public function __get($property) 
{
    if(property_exists($this, $property) {
        return $this->{$property};
    }
}
```

Edit:
Actually when i've checked the usage again; it would be better to have a method in the class field_seo_multidomain so making checks/validations in this method would be more useful

```
public function getText($lang, $domain){
    if(property_exists($this, $lang) {
        if(property_exists($this->{$lang}, $domain) {
            return $this->{$lang}->{$domain}->field_seo->field_meta_description->value;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Then an app/view side you can call;

```
echo $myObject->field_seo_multidomain->getText($lang_arr[$language], $domains_arr[$domain]);
```

if the language property or domain property does not exist it will just echo an empty string, you can also add fallback language feature with this approach.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the call to the function ? I mean, the part outside the class. I don't catch how to call it for every single possible property. Thanks!!

Comment: @Cesar i've edited the answer, can you check again, if it fits your usage?

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks!